# Win32 API Not Properly Hooking Sockets

Tags: c++, c, winapi, winsock, win32-process

Hello im trying to Hook Sockets to read, and modify traffic from within my browsers (Chrome/IE). The Hooks are not working properly. Im not seeing any packets, Im not to sure what I'm doing wrong. I do not want to use any library such as Detours, Im only interested in pure Win32 API. Below is my code, :)

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")


  #ifndef MAX_PATH
  #define MAX_PATH _MAX_PATH
  #endif

  using namespace std;

  BYTE hook[6];
  BYTE hook2[6];
  BYTE jmp[6] = { 0xe9,0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 ,0xc3 };
  ofstream myfile;
  ofstream myfile2;
  DWORD pPrevious;

  void showProcessInformation();
  DWORD HookFunction(LPCSTR lpModule, LPCSTR lpFuncName, LPVOID lpFunction, unsigned 
  char *lpBackup)
  {
    DWORD dwAddr = (DWORD)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle((LPCWSTR)lpModule), lpFuncName);
      ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPVOID)dwAddr, lpBackup, 6, 0);
      DWORD dwCalc = ((DWORD)lpFunction - dwAddr - 5);
      VirtualProtect((void*)dwAddr, 6, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &pPrevious);
      memcpy(&jmp[1], &dwCalc, 4);
      WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPVOID)dwAddr, jmp, 6, 0);
      VirtualProtect((void*)dwAddr, 6, pPrevious, &pPrevious);
      FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess(), 0, 0);
     return dwAddr;
   }

   BOOL UnHookFunction(LPCSTR lpModule, LPCSTR lpFuncName, unsigned char *lpBackup)
  {
       DWORD dwAddr = (DWORD)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle((LPCWSTR)lpModule), lpFuncName);

       if (WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPVOID)dwAddr, lpBackup, 6, 0))
       return TRUE;
      FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess(), 0, 0);
     return FALSE;
   }


  int  nSend(SOCKET s, const char *buf, int len, int flags) {
  UnHookFunction("ws2_32.dll", "send", hook);
  int result = send(s, buf, len, flags);

  myfile.open("C:\tmp\log.txt", ios::app | ios::binary);
  myfile << buf;
  myfile.close();
  HookFunction("ws2_32.dll", "send", (LPVOID*)nSend, hook);
  return result;
   }



 int nRecv(SOCKET s, char* buf, int len, int flags)
 {
 UnHookFunction("ws2_32.dll", "recv", hook2);
 DWORD tmp;

 len = recv(s, buf, len, flags);
  if (len > 0)
  {
    std::cout << "Inside Chrome Socket " << buf;
    myfile2.open("C:\tmp\log.txt", ios::app | ios::binary);
    myfile2 << buf;
    myfile2.close();
  }

  HookFunction("ws2_32.dll", "recv", (LPVOID*)nRecv, hook2);
    return len;
 }
```

Below is the DLL Main Entry Point

```
 BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                   DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                   LPVOID lpReserved
                 )
 {

switch (ul_reason_for_call)
{
case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    
    AllocConsole();
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    
    HookFunction("ws2_32.dll", "send", (LPVOID*)nSend, hook);
    HookFunction("ws2_32.dll", "recv", (LPVOID*)nRecv, hook2);


    break;
case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    HookFunction("ws2_32.dll", "send", (LPVOID*)nSend, hook);
    HookFunction("ws2_32.dll", "recv", (LPVOID*)nRecv, hook2);
    break;
case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    break;
case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    break;
}


return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices).

Comment: because app can not use `send` and `recv`. but for instance `WSASend` and `WSARecv` or even `WSASendMsg`. because this - need do hook inside `WSPPROC_TABLE` - this is posible found this in heap

Comment: and for *and modify traffic* simply hook send and recv api not enough (espesially in https case) need hook WSPConnect and make proxy pair - for all traffic go via your sockets

Comment: Also, several technical issues. When patching code you will want to call [FlushInstructionCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-flushinstructioncache) once done writing. Though you shouldn't be writing into the middle of instructions (which, likely, you are). You should take advantage of the fact, that most API calls are [prepared for hot-patching](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110921-00/?p=9583), conveniently solving that issue.